# template specialization in another file c++. Which version gets

Tags: c++, templates, g++, template-specialization, icc

I have these files :-

1.h :-

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename A>
void f() {
  cout<<"generic\n";
}
```

1.cpp :-

```
#include "1.h"

template <>
void f<int> () {
  cout<<"for ints only\n";
}
```

main.cpp :-

```
#include "1.h"

int main() {
  f<int>();
  return 0;
}
```

Now, I compile and run these with g++ like this :-

```
g++ -c 1.cpp -o 1.o 
g++ main.cpp 1.o
./a.out
```

And I get :-

```
for ints only
```

On the other hand, I compile it with icpc like this :-

```
icpc -c 1.cpp -o 1.o
icpc main.cpp 1.o
./a.out
```

And I get :-

```
generic
```

What does the C++ standard say about this? Is any one compiler "right" and the other "wrong" or is the standard ambiguous on this issue and both are "right" ?

Comment: I'd believe _g++_ is right here, but the undefined behavior lands are tricky...

Comment: In the eloquent words of the C++ language standard:  When writing a specialization / be careful
about its location / or to make it compile / will be such a trial / as to kindle its self-immolation.

Comment: @K-ballo That's what I'd believe too. But I'd like a pointer to an authoritative source that states this one way or another.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your program exhibits undefined behavior.  The specialization must be declared in every translation unit in which it is used, per C++11 §14.7.3/6:

> If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is explicitly specialized then that specialization shall be declared before the first use of that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation to take place, in every translation unit in which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required.